# Seeds segmentation in OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I know that this topic has been covered before but I'm stuck.
I'm quite new and I trying to segment a seeds using Python and OpenCV

[Here is my steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e7CL.png)

And now I'm stuck on how to separate the 3 seeds in the center of the image. Then I use the distance transformation, but the result is not satisfactory (why it is hardly visible?). I don't know how to proceed further. I would like to achive something like this.

[Distance transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLd5x.png)

In more circular object dt works well but not in my case.

My code:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('connected_seeds.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(600,400))

# Gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Blur image
blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 7)

# Thresholding
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Closing
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

sure_bg = cv2.dilate(closing,kernel,iterations=2)

# Distance transform
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(closing, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.5*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
```

here is the article I'm following:
https://learning.rc.virginia.edu/notes/opencv/

Comment: `(why it is hardly visible?)` A distance transform replaces each pixel with the number of pixels that it is away from a zero pixel. If you scale the image up or down in resolution, you change how far apart two pixels are, and so you change the brightness of the distance transform. If you look at the next line of the article you are following, you will see this: `cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.6*dist_transform.max(),255,0)` They are using the maximum of the image to choose the distance transform threshold.

Comment: If you look at the tutorial you're following, they don't actually get the seeds separated until they apply the watershed algorithm.

Comment: @NickODell Yes, you are right. After put the original image size not it works. But i have another problem with separating seeds. I'm using morphological operations without much result.

https://ibb.co/VJgTC6G

For more rounded objects such as coins erode wil be nice way to separate them but not in my case. The Seeds have an irregular shape.  I don't know how to go further.

Comment: I just wonder if  is at all possible to separate these objects. As you can see in the article the autor didn't get fully separated cells either.